# Spring Security: password don't match with stored one

Tags: spring, security

I have a problem with password hashing. I want to appply sha-256 with salt and 1024 iterations to authenticate my users using Spring Security. But somehow, my password in database dont match those from user input.

Here is my code:

**security-context.xml**

```
<beans:bean
    id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" >
    <beans:constructor-arg value="256" />
    <beans:property
        name="iterations"
        value="1024" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource" id="saltSource">
    <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="id"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userLoginDetails" >
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" >
             <salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**userLoginDetails**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserLoginDetails implements UserDetailsService {

private EregDaoFactory daoFactory;

@Autowired
public void setDaoFactory(EregDaoFactory daoFactory) {
    this.daoFactory = daoFactory;
}

/**
 * Retrieves a user record containing the user's credentials and access.
 */
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,
        DataAccessException {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

    int userId = Integer.parseInt(username);

    UzytkownikDao dao = daoFactory.getUzytkownikDao();

    LoggedUser user = null;
    Uzytkownik dbUser = null;

    try {

        dbUser = (Uzytkownik) dao.findById(Integer.parseInt(username));
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grants = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        Collection<Object> userNames = new ArrayList<Object>();

        if (dbUser.getRola() == 'U') {
            grants.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_STUDENT"));
            userNames = daoFactory.getUczenDao().getNameAndLastName(userId);

        } else if (dbUser.getRola() == 'N') {
            grants.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TEACHER"));
            userNames = daoFactory.getNauczycielDao().getNameAndLastName(userId);
        } else if (dbUser.getRola() == 'O') {
            grants.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PARENT"));
            userNames = daoFactory.getOpiekunDao().getNameAndLastName(userId);
        }
        grants.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        Object[] names = userNames.toArray();
        user =
                new LoggedUser(username, dbUser.getHaslo(), true, true, true, true, grants,
                        (String) names[0], (String) names[1], dbUser.getRola());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error in retrieving user");

    }

    return user;

}
```

}

**LoggedUser**

```
    package ereg.security.userdetails;

public class LoggedUser extends User {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String id;
private final String imie;
private final String nazwisko;
private final char rola;
private Date lastSuccessfulLogin;
private String lastKnowIpAddress;

public LoggedUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
        boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String name, String lastName, char rola) {
    super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
            authorities);
    this.imie = name;
    this.nazwisko = lastName;
    this.rola = rola;
    this.id = username;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getImie() {
    return imie;
}

public String getNazwisko() {
    return nazwisko;
}

public char getRola() {
    return rola;
}

public Date getLastSuccessfulLogin() {
    return lastSuccessfulLogin;
}

public String getFormattedDate() {
    if (lastSuccessfulLogin != null) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss").format(lastSuccessfulLogin);
    } else
        return null;
}

public String getLastKnowIpAddress() {
    return lastKnowIpAddress;
}

public void setLastSuccessfulLogin(Date lastSuccessfulLogin) {
    this.lastSuccessfulLogin = lastSuccessfulLogin;
}

public void setLastKnowIpAddress(String lastKnowIpAddress) {
    this.lastKnowIpAddress = lastKnowIpAddress;
}
```

}

And here is the program that hashes passwords:

**EncryptAllUsersPasswords**

```
private void encryptPasswords() throws Exception {
    OneWayEncryptor encryptor = OneWayEncryptor.getInstance();

    appContext =
            new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
                    "C:/EclipseWorkSpace/myereg/WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");

    ds = (DataSource) appContext.getBean("dataSource");
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    BigDecimal userId = null;
    String password = "";
    String encrypted = "";

    Map<?, ?> row = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    for (Iterator<?> it = jdbc.queryForList("SELECT id, haslo FROM UZYTKOWNIK").iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        row = (Map<?, ?>) it.next();

        userId = (BigDecimal) row.get("ID");
        password = (String) row.get("HASLO");
        encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(password, userId.toString());

        System.out.println(userId.toString());

        jdbc.execute("UPDATE UZYTKOWNIK SET haslo = '" + encrypted + "'  WHERE id = " + userId);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EncryptAllUserPasswords encrypt = new EncryptAllUserPasswords();
    try {
        encrypt.encryptPasswords();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**OneWayEncryptor**

```
public final class OneWayEncryptor {
private static final OneWayEncryptor INSTANCE = new OneWayEncryptor();

private static final int ITERATIONS = 1024;
private static final String ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";

private OneWayEncryptor() {
}

public static OneWayEncryptor getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;

}

public String encrypt(String plaintext, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

    messageDigest.reset();
    messageDigest.update(salt.getBytes());

    byte[] btPass = messageDigest.digest(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        messageDigest.reset();
        btPass = messageDigest.digest(btPass);
    }

    String encodedPassword = byteToBase64(btPass);

    return encodedPassword;
}

private String byteToBase64(byte[] bt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bt));

}
```

}

I believe that problem lies in the last one... Please help

Comment: How were the database versions generated?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add that. Please see updated question

Comment: Have you tried it without the salt?  Take that out so you have fewer moving parts and get it working.  Once you are comfortable with that, add the salt back in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip digitaljoel. It does not work without salt, either.

Comment: Actually, I found sth: byte[] btPass = messageDigest.digest(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        messageDigest.reset();
        btPass = messageDigest.digest(btPass);
    }
for ITERATIONS == 1 isn't it 2 iterations together? the first one before for loop and the one inside. Now it works, but still got problems with salt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, this worked:

```
public String encrypt(String plaintext, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String pass = plaintext + "{" + salt + "}";
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

    messageDigest.reset();
    byte[] btPass = messageDigest.digest(pass.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS - 1; i++) {
        messageDigest.reset();
        btPass = messageDigest.digest(btPass);
    }

    String hashedPass = new BigInteger(1, btPass).toString(16);
    if (hashedPass.length() < 32) {
        hashedPass = "0" + hashedPass;
    }

    return hashedPass;
}
```

can someone tell my why? I mean why when i tried using update(salt) method it didint and when i switch to concate string it did. and i dont mind part with "{salt}", cause that only allows me to generate exactly the same hash as spring does. the thing is that before it generated wrong hash even with given salt. I checked it with sha256 generators. Can someone tell me why it started working after string concatating?

Comment: I struggled for a few hours before finding this solution. I debugged Spring source code to find out this is the only way it matches with the hash created by Spring.